# Getting position in a list and comparasion

Tags: c#, list, search, comparison

I am trying to get positions in a list of some values to compare them with another list.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= commands.ToArray().Length; i++)
{
    levensheteinvalues_commands.Add(commands.ToArray()[i].ToString());
    levensheteinvalues_numbers.Add(
        Program.ComputeLevenshteinDistance(args[0], 
            commands.ToArray()[i].ToString()));
}
for (int i = 0; i <= commands.ToArray().Length; i++)
{
    if (smallestlevensheteinvalue == 0)
    {
        smallestlevensheteinvalue = levensheteinvalues_numbers[i];
    }
    else if (smallestlevensheteinvalue > levensheteinvalues_numbers[i])
    {
        smallestlevensheteinvalue = levensheteinvalues_numbers[i];
    }

}
var indexes = levensheteinvalues_numbers.GetIndexes(smallestlevensheteinvalue);
```

Why doesn't

```
var indexes = levensheteinvalues_numbers.GetIndexes(smallestlevensheteinvalue);
```

work? And when I get the value how can I compare it to another list?

Comment: "doesn't work" means what?

Comment: As in it gives me an error on compile: Error 5 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' does not contain a definition for 'GetIndexes' and no extension method 'GetIndexes' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Boncey Pineappel\Documents\Programming\PCMR-Bot\PCMR-Bot\GroupChatHandler.cs 160 62 PCMR-Bot

Comment: Why are you using `==` in you loop, why you are converting enumerable to array, what's the point of the second loop, your code would never work!

Comment: Okay, and which part of the error message from the compiler is unclear? After all, it is plain English...

Comment: Fixed the == now I need to fix the get indexes part, any ideas. I want to find out which positions the smallest number is in in my list.

Comment: @Boncey: `<=` in your code still causes index outside the array error!

Comment: What makes you think `GetIndexes` exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have posted have some serious problems. This `May` solve your problem since your code as well as your approach is very unclear and ambiguous. I have blindly edited the code to fix the serious problems.

```
for (int i = 0; i < commands.Count(); i++) {
     levensheteinvalues_commands.Add(commands.ElementAt(i).ToString()); 
     Program.ComputeLevenshteinDistance(args[0], commands.ElementAt(i).ToString()));
}
for (int i = 0; i < commands.Count(); i++) {
     if (smallestlevensheteinvalue == 0)
     {
         smallestlevensheteinvalue = levensheteinvalues_numbers[i];
     }
     else if (smallestlevensheteinvalue > levensheteinvalues_numbers[i])
     {
         smallestlevensheteinvalue = levensheteinvalues_numbers[i];
     }
}
int index = levensheteinvalues_numbers.IndexOf(levensheteinvalues_numbers.Min());
```